# Passing Extra Parameters in Vuetify Rules Definition

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

My goal is to define my rules once and then reuse them for all of my fields. To do this, I need to pass extra parameters to my rules, like maxlength of 20 on one v-text-field, but a maxlength of 50 on another. From what I see, only the value is getting passed. How can I add extra parameters to my rules?

```
<template>
  <v-input :rules=[rules.max(20)] v-model="field1" />
  <v-input :rules=[rules.max(50)] v-model="field2" />
</template>
<script>    
  data() {
    rules: {
      max(v, maxnum) { //maxnum is the parameter I want to add so that I can pass different values and reuse the same rule on multiple fields
        return (v || '').length <= maxnum || 'Max exceeded';
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 20):

You need a function that **returns** the rule function. The wrapper function should accept any extra params that the `rules` function doesn't know about (anything other than the value):

```
<template>
  <v-input :rules=[rules.max(20)] v-model="field1" />
  <v-input :rules=[rules.max(50)] v-model="field2" />
</template>

<script>    
  data() {
    rules: {
      max(maxNum) {
        return v => (v || '').length <= maxNum || 'Max exceeded';
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

just pass v-model variable as second parameter to your rule.

```
<template>
  <v-input :rules=[rules.max(20, field1)] v-model="field1" />
  <v-input :rules=[rules.max(50, field1)] v-model="field2" />
</template>

<script>    
  data() {
    rules: {
      max(maxnum, v) { 
        return (v || '').length <= maxnum || 'Max exceeded';
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: By default the value is passed to the rule function already so no need to pass it in.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda No it doesn't. You need to manually add it when sending own parameters.

Answer (score 2):

This is easily implemented by resorting to a high-order-function:

```
<template>
  <v-input :rules=[rules.max(20)] v-model="field1" />
  <v-input :rules=[rules.max(50)] v-model="field2" />
</template>
<script>    
  data() {
    rules: {
      max: (maxnum) => (value) => {
        return (v || '').length <= maxnum || 'Max exceeded'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Like this `rules.max(5)` returns `(value) => return (v || '').length <= 5 || 'Max exceeded'`

Comment: This is much cleaner. With typescript though, whats the highest order functions type?

Comment: it's a function that gets a number and returns a function that gets an number and returns a validation result. I suppose that the validation result is boolean | string

Comment: I ended up creating a custom type that allowed multiple parameters. Not sure if this is correct but its working. `export type ValidationFunction<T> = ( s: T, b?:T, d?:T ) => (c:  T) =>  boolean | string`

Comment: // I guess this
type Validation =  (value: string) => string | boolean;

(maxnum:number): Validation => (value:string) => {
        return (v || '').length <= maxnum || 'Max exceeded'
      }

Answer (score 1):

## Quasar example

The **rules** property expects an array. This is one of the correct ways to do it:

```
<template>
  <!-- ... -->
  <q-input
     v-model="username"
     label="Username"
     :rules="maxRule(30)"
     />
  <!-- ... -->
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {
  setup (props) {
    const username = ref(null)
    const maxRule = (limit) => [val => val.length <= limit || `Please use maximum ${limit} characters`]
    return {
      username,
      maxRule 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using composition API this is the right way:

```
<template>
  <!-- ... -->
  <q-input
     v-model="username"
     label="Username"
     :rules="rules.max(250)"
     />
  <!-- ... -->
</template>

<script setup>
const rules = {
    max: (limit) => val => val.length <= limit || `Le champ ne doit pas avoir plus  ${limit} caractères`
};
</script>
```